# Double twisted connect wall

Tags: connect-wall

This puzzle continues on the trend of connect-walls (a bit late for the [Topic Challenge #42](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7045/60644), I'm afraid), but with some twists.

First, it's a double connect-wall! The following image can be separated in 4 groups of 4 squares... but in two ways. After finding these groupings, you'll have to rearrange the squares in columns and rows according to these groups and the clues under the image. And then, I'll want **a name**, and **why this name is relevant** to this puzzle.

---

[image: Four by four grid of squares, where each cell has a central large number and a smaller upper-right corner number. Each parentheses corresponds to a particular cell. With the larger number listed first, the values reading left-to-right and then top-to-bottom are: (1021958, 0), (2051729, 6), (3111852, 1), (4041866, 8), (4101957, 4), (6081945, 1), (9011932, 0), (11021970, 1), (12021809, 2), (14072002, 6), (14101912, 0), (18051980, 1), (21092001, 2), (22111890, 5), (26111965, 9), (30061908, 7)]

**Rows:** Failed beginning of heavenly rapid expansion
**Columns:** Rising mother dream kiss

---

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are all

> **dates** of historical events!

They are grouped as follows:

> * The dates national leaders were born
>  * The dates explosions(both natural and non-natural) happened
>  * The dates satellites first were launched in space
>  * The dates failed assassination attempts occurred

After groupoing these, you'll notice

> that these events are all **either** french, american(USA), japanese, russian. So the next step will be to group these country by country.

Here's an image of my result:

> [image] The last square, I obtained from the given clues. **Rows**(in order): Failed(from failed assassinat.), Beginning(from date of birth), of Heavenly(from satellite), Rapid expansion(from explosion).  **Columns**(in order): Rising(from *Rising* sun, implying Japan), Mother(from *Mother* Russia), dream(from American *dream*), kiss(from French *kiss*).

Now, looking at this new square's numbers, they seem to represent

> The years 806, 1625, 1409, 1712. I have seen some connections between them but nothing that has given me an "AHA!-reaction". Maybe someone in here can finish this last step!

**EDIT**: Thanks @Prince deepthinker!

> - The numbers on the last grid are the exact date of birth and death (8th June 1625 - 14th September 1712) of the Italian mathematician **Giovanni Domenico Cassini!**. Also, how he is connected to this puzzle beacuase it involves 1) His **date of birth** 2) He was also an astronomer and has a **launched satellite** named after him. 3) He worked for **King Louis XIV** who also happened to have an **assassination attempt** on him. 4) He's a **mathematician** and this is a number-puzzle :)

Note:

> The grid to the left were just simple notations to remember them. Also, I will add/edit more details a bit later when I have more time.

Comment: Nice work :) Another possibility for the next step - rot13(vafgrnq bs lrnef, lbh zvtug unir 8 cnvef bs 2-qvtvg ahzoref pbeerfcbaqvat guebhtu N1M26 gb yrggref bs gur nycunorg - gur ahzoref pregnvayl frrz gb or va gur evtug xvaq bs enatr, nygubhtu lbh znl arrq gb fjnc fbzr ebjf/pbyhzaf gb trg nalguvat zrnavatshy...?) Just an idea at this stage, nothing more...

Comment: Thx :).. Hmm, i'll check

Comment: Giovanni Domenico Cassini: Look at his birth and death dates. 08/06/1625 - 14/09/1712

Comment: Ha, so I was half right! :)

Comment: @Prince deepthinker Nice spot! I'll add that in :)

Comment: Stiv I didn't even look at your comment tbh

Comment: It is relevant to this because he was a mathematician and this puzzle is based on numbers.

Comment: There's also [this connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini%E2%80%93Huygens) to one of the group categories. Maybe there are even more...

Comment: Great job! And as Stiv pointed out, the relation to Saturn unlocks even more connections ;)